# WebView SaveToString() Equivalent

Tags: webview, windows-10, windows-10-mobile

I have been using SaveToString() method to get the source code of the page in WebBrowser Control. But since its been deprecated in Windows 10, **Whats the equivalent for SaveToString() in WebView Control of Windows 10.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WebView allows us to invoke script, and we can dump the document.documentElement.outerHTML to do the same thing as SaveToString().

The following shows a very simple sample for your test. Note that I didn't try to make a cool UI design and make all things formatted, but only try to show you the idea.

**In xaml**:

```
    <StackPanel>
        <WebView x:Name="MyWebView" Source="http://www.bing.com" Height="200" 
                 DOMContentLoaded="MyWebView_DOMContentLoaded"/>
        <Button x:Name="ViewSourceBtn" Content="View Source" Click="ViewSourceBtn_Click"/>
        <RichTextBlock x:Name="SourceBlock" Height="300" >
        </RichTextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
```

**Code behind**:

```
    bool contentloaded = false;
    private async void ViewSourceBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (contentloaded)
        {
            string html = await MyWebView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { "document.documentElement.outerHTML;" });
            var paragraph = new Paragraph();
            paragraph.Inlines.Add(new Run { Text = html });
            SourceBlock.Blocks.Clear();
            SourceBlock.Blocks.Add(paragraph);
        }
        else
        {
            string err = "Waiting for HTML content to load!";
            var paragraph = new Paragraph();
            paragraph.Inlines.Add(new Run { Text = err });
            SourceBlock.Blocks.Clear();
            SourceBlock.Blocks.Add(paragraph);
        }
    }

    private void MyWebView_DOMContentLoaded(WebView sender, WebViewDOMContentLoadedEventArgs args)
    {
        contentloaded = true;
    }
```

Here is the result by clicking view source button:
[image]